# hashtag and !, at the end of url. how can I remove it, why is it there.

Tags: angularjs, node.js, dns

I am seeing '/#!/' at the end of my url and I am not sure where it is coming from. I am using Nodejs Angularjs.

Comment: Hi Sergio welcome to stackoverflow, can you source your project files so your viewers can take a look? are you using a cli? or building it from scratch.

Comment: It's a "she-bang" or "hash bang".  You using unix or linux?

Comment: It's because that's how client side routing works # is being used as escape character for splitting the URL. Go through this link you will get better understanding http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/deep-dive-into-client-side-routing-navigo-pushstate-hash

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Angularjs, you need to set the location provider to use html 5 mode:

```
myModule.config(['$locationProvider',
  function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

Also, ensure you have the `<base href="/">` set in your page that serves your angular application.  For me, an example would be in my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">
  <title>Super Cool App</title>
...
...
```